# Адаптирование изображения

Tags: css, javascript

```
var href = "2.jpg";

var img = new Image();
img.src = href;

var imgWidth = img.width; //длина картинки*/

if(imgWidth>screen.width){

}
```

Затея в том, что если изображение больше, чем ширина браузера, то сделать его под ширину браузера или чуть меньше.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<img src="/" style="max-width: 100%" />
```

Comment: прикольно, всего лишь